# Optimizing huge gps tracks drawing in google earth plugin

Tags: javascript, performance, google-earth-plugin

I have gps routes that have about 20.000 points for each. I want to draw them on google earth plugin (using google earth api). Here's the simple code to do that:

```
var drawTracks = function(data) {
  var trackPlacemark = ge.createPlacemark("");
  var trackModel = ge.createLineString("");
  trackPlacemark.setGeometry(trackModel);
  ge.getFeatures().appendChild(trackPlacemark);
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    trackModel.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(data[i].lat,data[i].lng,data[i].alt);
  }
}
```

It works, but it seems that data is too large, it takes about a minute to draw one track, after that plugin stuck for a second, and then track disappears.

So are there any solutions for improving the performance in this task? It seems there has to be on-the-fly line simplifying, and the quantity of points has to depend on the distance from the track.

I have already solved this task for 2D google maps - there I use [Mourner's simplify.js](http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/) and tile canvas engine ([here's my demo for 2d](http://kasheftin.github.io/gmaps/)). I need something similar for 3D.

I heard that google earth supports several variants for 3d model that have different levels of details, and it can substitude appropriate version that depends on the distance.

In my case one part of track might be very close to the point of view, and other - very far. I need to simplify only the far-part and recalculate it when the camera moves. I imagine something like division the space for cubic 3d tiles so that the polyline has different precision with dependency from the number of the tile cube that holds it.

Unlike google maps, earth is the blackbox, it's hard to understand what's going on inside, and what has been optimized. So any help with links, samples, optimizations of google earth plugin would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Say,20000points of 5 meters leg amounts to 100kilo meters view,
so you may not see detaill less 100 meters. 
Some points in less ten meters near can be negrected.

```
var j=k=0;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   if(Math.abs(data[i].lat-j)>0.00001||Math.abs(data[i].lng-k)>0.00001){
   j=data[i].lat;k=data[i].lng;
   trackModel.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(data[i].lat,data[i].lng,data[i].alt);
 }
}
```

Comment: Your solution suits for the case when all track is visible. The common case is when we follow some object that leaves the track behind, so that we see some part of the track from close distance, and this part we should not simplify. In contrast, there's the other part 20km away that should be simplified very much.